# CodeIgniter: blank page when a model contains a function

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

i'm using codeigniter for a website project. when i include a model, it will work as long as no function is implemented (except the constructor).

this configuration works:

```
class Xyz_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {

    }
}
```

this doesn't:

```
class Xyz_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function get_xyz() {
        return [        
            "xy" => ["xy"],
            "yz" => ["xy"],
            "zz" => ["xy","zx","zy"]
        ];
    }
}
```

there is not even an database access... and i have no clue why it is not working.

Comment: Can you better define "not working"?  Are there any specific errors?  What's the expected result?

Comment: How are you trying to access your model methods? Provide controller code.

Comment: i get a blank page after the "not working code" is implemented. without the "not working code" the page works. the model is autoloaded in config/autoload.php and is accessed with "$this->xyz_model->get_xyz();" but this makes no difference if there is any call of the model in a controller or not. it simply doesn't work when any function is implemented. i have no calls of this model in any controller at this moment.

Comment: any errors displayed in your error_log ? and does it make any difference if you dont auto load it but just with.... $this->load->model('xyz_model'); in your controller.... somewhere there must a error that doesnt get displayed properly.... also what version of CI are you using and what is your PHP version?

Comment: i'm using CI 3.0.0 on PHP 5.3.29. there is no error displayed in my log. and it does not make any difference using autoload or loading the model in the controller.

Comment: it simply stops doing anything after loading the model class.

Comment: i would recommend to start using PHP 5.5 (or higher), your php version might be the issue.... thats my best guess for now, copy pasted your code, everything works fine here in codeigniter

Comment: yep. that might be the issue. CI 3 requires php 5.4 or newer. i hope that will help ;)

Comment: problem solved... i should maybe update my php...

Answer (score 0):

You are extending the core model class, but the child's constructor is being used in placed of the parents:

```
parent::__construct();
```

Add that to your models constructor.

Comment: it doesn't make any difference. same result.

Answer (score 0):

use this

**In model**

```
class Xyz_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {

    }

    public function get_xyz() {
        $array = array(
            'xy' => 'xy',
            'yz' => 'xy',
            'zz' => array("xy","zx","zy")
        );
        return $array;
    }
}
```

**In controller**

```
$new = $this->Xyz_model->get_xyz()

print_r($new);
```

so **output** will be

```
Array ( [xy] => xy [yz] => xy [zz] => Array ( [0] => xy [1] => zx [2] => zy ) )
```